# ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, netcdf

I am trying to run a Python script that will compute statistical math and am receiving an error somewhere in the calculations that is throwing the below error about mismatching shapes (of a 2D array?). My input file is a netCDF file and the variable is simulated weather radar reflectivities.

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc_gen.py", line 75, in <module>
    temp[ens_mean_index] = calc
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (635047,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1905141,)
```

**all_ref1km_lambert.nc:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KhlnhB-0dhmt5JTS3E8YJ8QXm0bVyyfQ/view?usp=sharing

**Python Script (calc_gen.py):**

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import sys
import time
from array import array
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pygrib
import struct
from scipy.io import netcdf
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from scipy.io.netcdf import netcdf_file
from numpy import arange, dtype

my_example_nc_file = 'all_ref1km_lambert.nc'
nc = Dataset(my_example_nc_file, mode='r')

lons = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
lats = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
all_member_data = nc.variables['REFD_1000maboveground'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]

dx = 3.

nx = 1799
ny = 1059

count = 3

all_member_data = np.array(all_member_data)

ens_mean = np.mean(all_member_data, axis=0)

md_shape = ens_mean.shape
    
ens_dist = np.sort(all_member_data.flatten())[::-1]
    
calc = ens_dist[::count]

ens_mean_index = np.argsort(ens_mean.flatten())[::-1]
    
temp = np.empty_like(calc)
    
temp[ens_mean_index] = calc

calc = np.array(temp, dtype="<f")

calc_final = calc.reshape( md_shape )
```

Comment: Could you test and give the shape of your main variables along the code? Given only current code, it seems in line 75, you are assigning `pmm` of shape  `(635047,)` to `temp[ens_mean_index]` which is of shape  `(1905141,)`

Comment: Hi @lincr, that's correct. `calc` has a shape of `(635047,)` and `temp[ens_mean_index]` has a shape of `(1905141,)`. Are both variables supposed to have the same shape? If so, what's causing `temp[ens_mean_index]` to have such a high shape count?

Comment: First quesiton 1, no. There is a mechanism called `broadcasting` , see [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html) for a reference. For question 2,  `temp` and `calc` are of same shape while `ens_mean_index` has 3 times elements. Maybe it is related to `ens_dist[::count]`.

Comment: The key is to figure out the shape of `ens_mean` and `all_member_data`